# Can't facet on variable with more than 9 levels in python ggplot

Tags: python, python-ggplot

This code works:

```
import pandas as pd
from ggplot import *
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'facet_var': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1], 'hist_var': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]})
ggplot(aes(x='hist_var'), data = df) + geom_histogram() + facet_wrap('facet_var')
```

This code does not:

```
import pandas as pd
from ggplot import *
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'facet_var': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 'hist_var': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]})
ggplot(aes(x='hist_var'), data = df) + geom_histogram() + facet_wrap('facet_var')
```

The only change is adding a 0 to the final 1, making it 10 levels instead of 9. Any ideas?